# Looking for CMS/Wiki for IIS/SQL Server platform

Tags: cms, .net, wiki, sql-server

We are SaaS company and looking to update our web help portal. We can host ourselves, but prefer this to be more Microsoft-ish (SQL Server, IIS)

Currently we use Confluence, here is what we like:

- Easy to edit pages
- Was easy to setup and stores data in SQL Server (also not ALL of it)
- Able to store as PDF

What we DON't like:

- Right now we use their "starter" version. But we would like to close this documentation so only customers can see it (not whole WWW). We need software where we can setup users and permissions. Or somehow move it "behind" our authentication engine. I did not test extensively, but even if setting up user per customer works - it will be cost-prohibitive for what we need because those users only "viewers"
- Because confluence is "WIKI" - page is too busy with extra stuff we don't need. Who edited, "likes", links, dates, etc, etc. We need professional clean look to users who is NOT editor.
  More help/documentation like template with better side bar and more modern/pleasing template.

So, to summarize we need some kind of system which will:

- Have clean non-busy look
- Easy to edit
- Able to secure to authorized users only
- Editable by subject matters (not developers)
- Easy to add video/pictures

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Umbraco? It ticks all the 'basics' boxes of a .Net CMS, plus it has a 'package' ecosystem. A quick search on there for Video shows plenty of support for HTML5 files or YouTube embeds.

https://umbraco.com/why-umbraco

Answer (score 0):

This is a search I do every year or so, and thus far I've never fully settled on one preferred system.

I'd review the options listed here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Microsoft_ASP.NET
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/717523/Top-NET-Based-CMS-Content-Management-System

The overlapping references are not coincidence; Umbraco/Kentico/DNN/etc. are the most popular and established offerings. Personally I've tried DNN several times, but I accepted that I just don't get on with it.

All of these systems will cover your headline needs, but it's more a question personal preferences. Take a look at their feature lists and try the demo sites (where available).